# Google News RSS Feed -

Tags: php, xml, rss, google-news

Trying to get just a text description out of this good news feed, i dont' want the html but i can't find a common way to split it out..

http://news.google.co.uk/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&as_scoring=r&as_maxm=4&q=web+design&as_qdr=a&as_drrb=q&as_mind=6&as_minm=3&cf=all&as_maxd=5&output=rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to get the HTML data from the right XML-element (`<description>` in this case) you can just strip all HTML with PHP's [strip_tags](http://nl.php.net/strip_tags)

This seems to work like you want it:

```
$news = simplexml_load_file('http://news.google.co.uk/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&as_scoring=r&as_maxm=4&q=web+design&as_qdr=a&as_drrb=q&as_mind=6&as_minm=3&cf=all&as_maxd=5&output=rss');

foreach($news->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title . "\n";
    echo strip_tags($item->description) ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes i thought of that but it doesn't leave me with the same things each time and sometimes the first <font> tag isn't the main description.... :-(